# Sharing files from Win XP to Win 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, shared-folders

I have a computer with Windows XP (PC1) that acts as a File server. On this computer there is a shared Folder with some files.

I want to access those files in read/write from another computer with windows 7 (PC2).

I see PC1 from PC2 and I can access the folder and surf the subfolders and see the file, but if I try to open or copy one of those files from PC1 to PC2, I get an error that I need Admin rights to do that.

How can I let anyone to at least read files from the shared folder on PC1?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the security rights for the folder.
If it is shared folder, then right click on the folder, select Sharing and make sure there are Read and write for "all users".

Comment: the shared folder is on Win XP, the sharing panel does not have any user management, how do I enable user management?